# git hook post-merge - error: cannot run

Tags: git, githooks

To trigger a git hook after a pull i made a post-merge hook.
The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git log > gitlog.txt
```

The file is called 'post-merge' and has the same owner as the one that runs the pull command. Also it has the right permissions : 755.

When u do i git pull [remote] master i get this error:

```
error: cannot run .git/hooks/post-merge: No such file or directory
```

The post-merge file is in the .git/hooks folder.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may want to check if there is no CR or similar invisible character behind the sh.

This happens sometimes when a file passed through a windows system.

I think in vi it will show up a ^M

If that is the case remove it and it should work.

Comment: Thanx this is the right answer. I removed the CR in notepad++ by doing Edit->EOL Conversion-> UNIX Format.
It was on Windows Format and that has a CR LF

Comment: @PeterTillemans if only I could +10 this answer. This has had me stumped for at least 20 mins...