# Fix permissions with git post-merge

Tags: git, permissions, merge, githooks

On one server I work on, we must log in as root (for reasons I won't get into here). We have a git repository set up which is used for the web server, but since files are created as root, files modified by git have the wrong permissions.

I created an incredibly simple post-merge hook which I thought would solve the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
. git-sh-setup
chown -R www-data:www-data $GIT_DIR
```

I dropped this into `.git/hooks/post-merge` with execute permissions, but the file never seems to run. This is the first time I've tried to set up a hook, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

One thing I did notice is that most hooks had a `.sample` file, while post-merge did not. (git version 1.7.4)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try adding an `echo` or writing a `tmp` file in order to make sure it didn't run? Why a `post-merge` (on git pull) and not a `post-receive` (on `git push`)? If you don't do a `git pull` directly on the server, that particular hook (`post-merge`) won't run. What the `. git-sh-setup` line is supposed to do?

Comment: I did try writing a temp file. It doesn't appear that it gets executed. And I do pull directly on the server. My understanding is that git-sh-setup prepares necessary environment variables.

Comment: Can you post the actual commands you use when you do a pull (and expect the script to be run) ?

Comment: It's not when I pull, but rather when I merge. i.e. `git merge origin/feature-branch`. Ideally, I'd also like this hook to run with `git reset`. Really, any time git touches any file in this directory, I'd like to run the hook.

Comment: Hey, I know this is an old thread, but did you ever figure it out? I was hoping to add `chgrp -R group_name $GIT_DIR` as the file `post-merge`. Didn't see any good answers below...:q

Comment: @Jennings I accepted the answer that solved my problem. If you have a different problem, I'd suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have already known but you might want to check for the EOL characters (CRs) in your post-merge hook. This might explain why your hook doesn't execute (as mentioned in this other question [git-hook-post-merge-error-cannot-run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563904/git-hook-post-merge-error-cannot-run).

If this isn't the solution you could also possibly look at another approach for your problem. You could make a task to perform the owner changes to your directory when a file in your repository change on the server. Cron tasks on their own do not react based on filesystem changes, but you could take a stab at using something like [inotify](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) to react to changes in the server's git repository on any changes.

I hope that these two pieces of information either solve your problem or at least puts you closer. Good luck.

Comment: True, inotify would work.Doesn't look like there's a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you add the script to the super user group ownership.

Comment: The script was created as root.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are looking for the [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), if you wish the script to act the remote repository is pushed to.

Comment: No, I would like to use the post-merge hook.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the way "git achievements" works. It would be easier to wrap git in a script and do what you need at any command. Hooks are designed more for the remote repo rather than local. Merge is something you do locally so you won't find much help from the hook mechanisms.

Link:

http://benjamin-meyer.blogspot.com/2010/03/git-achievements.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Why is it messy? Git is made to be scripted. In fact, most git commands you use are actually bash scripts. Don't try and fit a round peg into a square hole by trying to fix this with hooks. Merging is something that focuses it's work in the working tree. Script is your savoir.

Comment: Well, if hooks worked the way I expected, my solution would be a two, perhaps three line shell script.

Writing a wrapper for git, while perhaps still fairly straightforward, is at least an order of magnitude more complicated.