# fatal: cannot run .git/hooks/commit-msg: No such file or directory in mac

Tags: git, github, version-control, githooks

I have never used git and have recently started using one.
I have created a branch locally.

```
FWS-CHE-LT-3532:amit$ git branch
* abc_123
  staging
FWS-CHE-LT-3532:amit$ git status
On branch abc_123
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/abc_123'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   api/app/controllers/constants/mproject_constants.rb
new file:   api/app/controllers/mproject_controller.rb
new file:   api/app/controllers/validationsmproject_validation.rb
new file:   app/blueprints/helpdesk/mproject_blueprint.rb
modified:   config/privileges.rb
modified:   config/routes/api/routes.rb
```

So when I am trying to execute `git commit -m "message"`, it is failing with fatal: cannot run `.git/hooks/commit-msg: No such file or directory`

What should I do??
I want to commit these changes and publish the branch so that I can raise a pull request for my team. Please Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git hook post-merge - error: cannot run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563904/git-hook-post-merge-error-cannot-run)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+cannot+run+.git%2Fhooks+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue.
It is possible, that the path to required python environment is not properly evaluated in the `commit-msg`-hook.

1. Check your local python version:

```
Python 3.6.5
```

2. Check if your `.git/hooks/commit-msg` sets the proper shebang, e.g.:
   `#!/usr/bin/env python3`